# Download Google Docs into String

Tags: java, file, download, document, google-docs

After searching for ages, I failed to find an article on how to download a Google Doc into a String (without formatting). Something like

```
String s = downloadDoc("https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gn9CMUIWpwldjgEO3cyg0Z_wQsOPzd37X0ehp6ZxOp0/edit?usp=sharing");
```

Is this possible using no libraries except for the built-in Java libraries?

Comment: Google docs/drive has rest api. So in theory you can access it without google libraries.   See https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/